# Tópico com mais de uma pergunta

Tags: debate, suporte

Nesse tópico, [Alternativa ao index.php usando .htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40693/duvida-sobre-o-htacess)

1. Achei o título muito vago.
2. O contexto apresenta duas questões, sendo uma bem específica e outra muito ampla, vaga.

É permitido múltiplas perguntas num único post?

Tentei buscar superficialmente aqui no meta e não encontrei nada relacionado.

Para o tópico citado, é correto editar o título para que se adeque ao contexto, pelo menos ao contexto da questão que está bem definida?

Comment: Daniel primeiro deveria dar essas indicações por comentário para que o AP (Autor da Pergunta) possa alterar a pergunta. Se nada foi feito, ai sim deverá ser fechada (se for realmente ampla demais).

Comment: Não comentei porque não sei se está correto.
O que pergunto aqui é, é correto corrigir sob o contexto que descrevi aqui?

Comment: Se acha que não está correto comente na pergunta. Eu tenho a mesma opinião que você. E quanto a fazer mais que uma pergunta não tem mal nenhum desde que estejam diretamente relacionadas. Isto a meu ver, veja o meu comentário: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40693/duvida-sobre-o-htacess#comment80113_40693

Comment: Por exemplo, se não concordar com o meu comentário, escreva outro em seguida do meu. Ou abra tópico aqui como fez agora :)

Comment: Acho que vc não entendeu... O que eu pergunto é se é correto editar a questão ou advertir mesmo num comentário.. É só isso.. não é questão de concordar contigo ou não ... rsrs só isso, simples..

Comment: Era isso que eu estava a tentar explicar. Eu acho correto fazeres isso, acabei mesmo eu por fazer como exemplo. Primeiro comentar, depois e se nada for feito, se achares que a pergunta vale a pena (se o conteúdo for bom) então edita.

Comment: Por exemplo [está edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/40693/2) acho que era escusada, uma vez que a pergunta tem outros problemas, esperava-se que o AP alterasse a pergunta conforme os comentários. Ou, depois, se já fosse para editar, já se alterava o que fosse necessário. Mas claro isto é somente a minha opinião.

Comment: Pra mim, "Dúvida sobre..." / "Ajuda com..." / "Problema com..." são títulos horrorosos. Se a pessoa está no SOpt é porque tem uma dúvida/problema e precisa de ajuda; e o título deve ser aproveitado para descrever a situação. Troquei lá, qualquer espécie de descrição é melhor que o original...

Comment: Aqui está uma edição que eu acho correta 1h depois da pergunta... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/40693/3

Comment: PS: é bacana deixar um comentário avisando da Meta discussão. Isso serve para aumentar a consciência de que o Meta existe.

Comment: @JorgeB. e demais concordo com suas obervações mas tem alguns usuários que não vão seguir as orientações nunca. Alguns não conseguem escrever nada compreensível. E tem gente que fica brava quando um post questiona se a presença de casos extremos em que a pessoa não evolui nunca é proveitosa para a comunidade. Eu costumo editar para arrumar o problema quando o usuário é novato. Em alguns casos deixo um comentário também. Quando não consigo melhorar porque está ruim demais, deixo o comentário. Nada muito detalhado. P/ usuários experientes eu deixo um link para o meta mostrando o erro.

Answer (score 4):

**No meu ponto de vista, é sim correto comentar e editar essa pergunta.**

Contudo, acho que deveríamos ter em atenção alguns passos:

1. Comentar a pergunta, dizendo o que acha que a pergunta pode ter de errado e, o que o AP pudesse alterar;
2. Ter em atenção se a pergunta pode gerar respostas vagas, se sim mais vale fechar e avisar o AP (sendo novato) que a pergunta está sendo suspensa mas que poderá ser reaberta se ele alterar a pergunta;
3. Esperar algum tempo, para ver se o AP altera a pergunta;
4. Se o **ponto 2 não se verificar** e o ponto 3 já estiver esgotado, alterar a pergunta para que possa ser mais objetiva.
5. Caso ocorra algum problema que não saiba resolver ou que tenha dúvidas, abrir uma pergunta no Meta como foi feito neste caso.

**Quanto a pergunta**

> É permitido múltiplas perguntas num único post?

Acho que esta pergunta aqui é um bom exemplo disso mesmo: foram feitas duas perguntas numa só aqui no meta, sobre o título e o contexto da outra postagem. Como os pontos 1 e 2 da pergunta estão interligados, puderam ser respondidos objetivamente.

Comment: Entendido! Só não concordo que para esse caso específico, as duas perguntas sejam "interligadas". Expliquei no primeiro post que a primeira questão é bem definida e clara, sobre modificar o directory index pelo htaccess.
Em seguida vem uma questão de uma forma muito vaga -> "Também gostaria de saber algumas configurações defensivas que ele permita fazer sobre diretórios." <- Isso é vago demais.. Defensiva ? Não permitir a listagem de arquivos do diretório? Colocar senha para acesso ao diretório? Enfim, por isso acho que não deveria misturar a segunda questão. Deveria estar num outro tópico.

Comment: Aí que entrou a minha dúvida se isso era permitido no SO-pt ou não. do meu ponto de vista fica muito bagunçado porque o título é bem específico sobre o directoryIndex e no contexto traz outros assuntos, entende? Então quer dizer que se eu encontrar esse tipo de situação, eu posso julgar que a questão estava de forma errada e pedir ao usuário que crie outro tópico? Mas entra em contradição com a interpretação de outros que pensem diferente.  Precisamos de um consenso.

Comment: @DanielOmine Concordo com você, a segunda parte pode ser removida, e o autor orientado a postar uma segunda pergunta mais específica (e também mais clara e detalhada).

Comment: @bfavaretto nesse caso sim, eu apenas estava a generalizar, porque a pergunta do AP foi "É permitido múltiplas perguntas num único post?". Eu respondi que sim, se estiverem ligadas, se corresponderem ao mesmo tipo da dúvida e se forem objetivas. Não sei se me faço entender.